# Hierarchy select not working in Visual Studio / SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, function, sql-server-2012

This function working on my friend's Visual Studio and SQL Server 2021 but not mine.

It returns an error at `WITH Result (ID)`:

> *incorrect syntax near "Result", Expecting AW_CHANGE_TRACKING_CONTEXT,AW_ID, AW_XMLNAMESPACES, QUOTED_ID*

Any solutions..?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[hierarchySelect]
(
@CategoryID int
)
RETURNS @Result TABLE (ID int) AS BEGIN


WITH Result (ID)
AS
(
    SELECT ID
    FROM Categories
    WHERE ID = @CategoryID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C.ID FROM Categories C
    INNER JOIN Result R ON C.parentID = R.ID
)
INSERT INTO @Result
SELECT ID
FROM Result

RETURN

END
GO
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  SQL Server 2000, for instance, doesn't support the `with` statement.

Comment: its Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, it should be Results not result but thats wired because its working on my friend sql server I don't know how.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[hierarchySelect]
(
@CategoryID int
)
RETURNS @Result TABLE (ID int) AS BEGIN


WITH Result (ID)
AS
(
SELECT ID
FROM Categories
WHERE ID = @CategoryID
UNION ALL
SELECT C.ID FROM Categories C
INNER JOIN Results R ON C.parentID = R.ID
)
INSERT INTO @Result
SELECT ID
FROM Results

RETURN

END
GO
```